# When naming a card, can you name a card that doesn't exist?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Inspired by the new card [You Are Already Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=You%20Are%20Already%20Dead).

There's a combo deck that wins with [Thassa's Oracle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thassa%27s%20Oracle), then playing [Spoils of the Vault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spoils%20of%20the%20Vault) in response to the Oracle's trigger to exile their entire library. The win is deterministic - once Spoils resolves the game is over. Opponent probably won't concede though, since they get to see what else is in the deck for sideboarding equity.

One consequence of this is that when naming a card with Spoils of the Vault, it's become rather common to name You Are Already Dead, since the opponent really is "already dead". It's a way to poke fun at them and/or to tilt them.

Question: are you allowed to name even more stupid, non-existent card names like "I'm Still At 20 Lol" or "Your Wife Is Cheating On You" to tilt them even more?

NB: for the combo to work, one needs to name a card not in the deck. You Are Already Dead is such a card, and other silly card names won't be in the deck either.

Comment: Technically the opponent can stifle the oracle trigger after spoils resolves, so it isn't a deterministic kill in many formats. E.g. [Overcharged Amalgam](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=%28oracle%3Acounter+oracle%3Atarget+oracle%3Atriggered+oracle%3Aability%29+legal%3Astandard) can do it in (2022) standard

Comment: awwww would've been a great loophole like vertical castling

Comment: @Caleth yes but it's unlikely - the combo is a top-tier combo and the only "commonly-played" card that can stop it is Stifle itself, but Stifle isn't even among the top 50 most-played Legacy spells right now (https://www.mtggoldfish.com/format-staples/legacy/full/spells). These spells also require mana to cast, and it's possible opponent either doesn't have the mana, or if they have the mana, then one can decline to combo.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems like this combo kills you before you get a chance to win the game.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus you need a third card to keep yourself alive - typically Phyrexian Unlife or Angel's Grace.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus you aren't drawing from an empty library, you are looking at the top X cards of an empty library, changing the order of those cards, and then winning, all in one ability

Comment: @Caleth: Spoils is the part that would kill you. You lose 1 life for each exiled card, so you need some way to survive that.

Comment: As an aside, the very similar [Demonic Consultation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Printings.aspx?multiverseid=184614)/Oracle combo in Vintage used [Abandon Hope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4635) for this purpose before You Are Already Dead was printed.

Comment: The trick is to rename your [___](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74252) to whatever name you want to use.  It doesn't even need to be in your deck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You have to name a card that exists.**

> **201.4.** If an effect instructs a player to choose a card name, the player must choose the name of a cardin the Oracle card reference. (See rule 108.1.) A player may not choose the name of a token unless it’ s also the name of a card.

For further explanation of what may or may not be named, here's a rather comprehensive [article on magicjudges.com](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rulestips/2012/11/tournament-tuesday-an-explanation-of-how-name-a-card-works/) on the subject.

Comment: What if the card exists, but just not in your deck?  That's all this exploit requires.  You could just pick something common and obvious like "Forest" if you know there's no green in your deck...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the combo as described names a card not in the deck. That isn't in question

Comment: This is [201.4 in the latest CRs](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220708.pdf); whatever site you are using for your rules reference is out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the note @PhilipKendall, I actually got it from https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr201/

Comment: @DarrelHoffman a ruling for Spoils of the Vault is "You don't have to choose the name of a card that's still in your library, or even a card that's in your deck at all. If no card with the chosen name is in your library, you exile your library and lose 1 life for each of those cards."   https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spoils%20of%20the%20Vault